# Decode ssl packets wireshark

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I'd like to know how to decode ssl packets in wireshark if I am using a service (Google Talk) that I should be able to see the keys for. Where are the keys for such an application and can I get a hold of them? I look for certs, but none for google.
I have worked with ssh keys and since I created them myself I know where they are, and can use them. But not for something like this.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the server's private key, which is highly unlikely to happen if the server you are connecting to does not belongs to you. 
Note that in addition to having this key, you also need to make sure that the transaction does not use Perfect Forward Secrecy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy), which you are able to do if you control the client side and the server does not require PFS.